# page.url() does not have page's url and return blank value

Tags: node.js, express, pdf, puppeteer, ejs

I want to get the page URL and generate PDF according to that new page is rendered, but when I load the new page the `page.url()` returns a blank value.

Anyone encountered a similar issue or know how to solve this issue thanks in advance.

```
 // Generate PDF file

(async () => {
  // The location

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    slowMo: 100,
  });

  var page = (await browser.pages())[0];
  const url = (await page.url()); // page.url should return me the current URL
```

for example:
"http://localhost:5000/articles/tv"

```
  console.log(url); // This returns blank value.

  await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "load" });

  await page.pdf({
    path: "page.pdf",
    format: "A4",
    printBackground: true,
    scale: 0.5,
    displayHeaderFooter: false,
    margin: { bottom: "50px" },
  });

  await browser.close();
})();


// Downloading PDF files
app.get("/downloadPDF", (req, res) => {
  // express.js
  res.download("./page.pdf");
});
//
```

Comment: Why would `page.url()` be anything but a blank value? The page starts out in an empty tab. You need to provide a URL or set some HTML onto that blank page. Your code right now says "Start out at a blank page. Then navigate to that same blank page." Which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I want to get the page URL and generate PDF according to that new page is rendered, but when I load new page the page.url() returns a blank value.

Comment: Right. The page URL is blank by default. What page URL are you trying to make a PDF from? Put that into your `goto` call rather than the blank value.

Comment: @ggorlen I want to open a new page and get that URL. To put it simply, I want it dynamic. I know and I can put Static URL to goto.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... What is a dynamic URL exactly?

Comment: @ggorlen I want to open any page then when I click generate PDF then the code fire and it should get the URL from the browser address bar and generate PDF"I mean the URL is dynamic because I open different pages.

Answer (score 2):

From the source you provided above, the page isn't loading any URL. Its URL is simply `about:blank`, So you'll get blank value.

```
  var page = (await browser.pages())[0];
```

This should be:

```
  var page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto(someURL)
```

or maybe you want to use the already opened tab in Puppeteer.

```
  var [page] = await browser.pages()
  await page.goto(someURL)
```

What are you trying to get or achieve by doing this?

If you want to generate PDF from a URL, you can use `page.goto(url)` and then `page.pdf()`.

```
await page.goto('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF')
await page.pdf({
    path: "page.pdf",
    format: "A4",
    printBackground: true,
    scale: 0.5,
    displayHeaderFooter: false,
    margin: { bottom: "50px" },
})
```

But if you're trying to print HTML tags, without navigating to any url, you can simply `page.setContent()` and then `page.pdf()` to print PDF from it.

```
const html = '<h3>PDF</h3><p>PDF is Portable Document Format</p>'
await page.setContent(html)
await page.pdf({
    path: "page.pdf",
    format: "A4",
    printBackground: true,
    scale: 0.5,
    displayHeaderFooter: false,
    margin: { bottom: "50px" },
})
```

Comment: I want to get the URL from the browser and then generate PDF. if I put URL statically it will work, but I don't want that.

Comment: `var [page] = await browser.pages()
  await page.goto(someURL)  // I need someURL should be dynamically taken from address bar`.

Comment: Are you trying to reload or something? Use the `await page.reload()` then.

Comment: That is the problem, the  `page.reload()`  returns blank value.